# Overlay horizontal text over bootstrap5 grid

Tags: css, css-grid, bootstrap-5

Working on my website, thought myself Boostrap5 and super happy about the outcome so far, but I want that the **name appears vertically on hover over the images on the bottom left**, but I am not sure where I am going wrong in my code. The text is placed very low and to the edge of the grid column.

I'm sure I'm going wrong with the `position:` attribute or something.

```css
.theteam img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.theteam img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.project img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.project:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.text-vertical {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about bg-dark p-5">
  <div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <h4 class="text-light text-capitalize mb-0">The rocking team</h4>
    <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/underline.png" alt="______"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="container theteam mt-5">
    <div class="row g-4 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project inline-block overlay">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/poyo_moya.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h6 class="text-white text-vertical position-absolute">Poyo Moya</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/regi-villardell.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Regi Vilardell</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/oriol_fontanals.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Oriol Fontanals</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/Patrick_obrien.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="">
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Patrick O'Brien</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The codepen link is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made updates to your **.text-vertical**, take a look:

UPD: I've made **.text-top** class to align text to top of the image.

```css
.theteam img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.theteam img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.project img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.project:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.text-vertical {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* here */
  width: fit-content;
  /* this line is important */
}

/* top align for vertical text */
.text-vertical.text-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3D(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about bg-dark p-5">
  <div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <h4 class="text-light text-capitalize mb-0">The rocking team</h4>
    <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/underline.png" alt="______">
  </div>

  <div class="container theteam mt-5">
    <div class="row g-4 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project inline-block overlay">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/poyo_moya.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h6 class="text-white text-vertical position-absolute">Poyo Moya</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/regi-villardell.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Regi Vilardell</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/oriol_fontanals.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Oriol Fontanals</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/Patrick_obrien.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="">
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical">Patrick O'Brien</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container theteam mt-5">
    <div class="row g-4 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project inline-block overlay">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/poyo_moya.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h6 class="text-white text-vertical text-top">Poyo Moya</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/regi-villardell.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical text-top">Regi Vilardell</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/oriol_fontanals.jpg" alt="team">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical text-top">Oriol Fontanals</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="https://poyo-pat-333.netlify.app/images/Patrick_obrien.jpg" alt="team">
        <div class="">
          <div>
            <h6 class="text-white text-vertical text-top">Patrick O'Brien</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome. This get's me a lot closer to my goal! Much appreciate that!

The only thing I don't know how to solve now is to have the text always on top of the image no matter how wide the column is. At the moment that changes depending on the viewport width.

Comment: @Boxhamster I've made **.text-top** class to align text to top of the image.

Comment: @Boxhamster if this answered your question, can you please accept this answer?